# Svg animation without css

Tags: animation, svg

I want to create an animation like this that revolves around the two shapes. And I want to achieve it in SVG with no external CSS. Can anyone help me out on how to do it?

This is my code

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="542" height="542" viewBox="0 0 542 542">
  <g id="svg" transform="translate(-655 -265)">
    <circle id="Ellipse_3" data-name="Ellipse 3" cx="271" cy="271" r="271" transform="translate(655 265)" fill="none"/>
    <path id="Path_1" data-name="Path 1" d="M818.25,412.875l.71.931c116.417,110.219-.023,204.664-.382,205.428-.045.089-.2.312-.375.672-2.758,5.713,3.239,3.015,3.594,2.858,147.217-64.969,210.869-212.39,210.672-213.249-.359-1.7-3.069-1.088-3.344-.781-4.366,4.893-81.574,88.727-207.317.617-.169-.118.317.2-.673-.473s-2.369-1.12-3.148-.181-.909,2.256.388,4.35" fill="none" stroke="#707070" stroke-width="1"/>
    <path id="Path_2" data-name="Path 2" d="M927.651,569.319s69.788,5.194,99.3,51.994c.017.04,4.351,6.826,5.406-.172a1.6,1.6,0,0,0,.069-.516,5.747,5.747,0,0,0-.21-2.031c-3.036-7.836-31.037-76.552-54.932-98.845-.009-.009-35.627,38.007-49.635,49.57" fill="none" stroke="#707070" stroke-width="1"/>
    <g id="Ellipse_1" data-name="Ellipse 1" transform="translate(655 496)" fill="#f90a2a" stroke="#000" stroke-width="1">
      <circle cx="34.5" cy="34.5" r="34.5" stroke="none"/>
      <circle cx="34.5" cy="34.5" r="34" fill="none"/>
      <animateTransform attributeName="transform" attributeType="XML" type="rotate" from="0" to="360" dur="10s" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
    </g>
  </g>
</svg>
```

[image: Text]

Comment: @RobertLongson Can you give me some guidance? I tried doing with it but I wasn't able to figure out how to do it.

Comment: This is the SVG I created. And I want to animate it.
https://codepen.io/alexios-leonidas/pen/gOxxqpR

Comment: I've done it. Can you help me with it?

Comment: It revolves around itself. I want it to revolve around the two shapes in the middle.

Comment: First step is to get rid of all those ``translates``, so all your further calculations will at least make sense; then learn [SMIL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/SVG_animation_with_SMIL)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you load your file into a vector editor, we will see that the shapes are outside the SVG canvas.

[image]

Because of this, you were forced to use transform commands to bring the forms back to the custom viewport.

*Practical advice*

It is necessary to draw in a vector editor so that the shapes do not go beyond the boundaries of the SVG canvas.

After redrawing in a vector editor and cleaning the file:

- To get a segment, use `stroke-dasharray="251,1004"`,
  where    `251` -
  dash, `1004` - gap
- To animate the rotation, it was necessary, in addition to the angle,
  to additionally specify the coordinates of the rotation center

```
<animateTransform attributeName="transform" attributeType="XML" type="rotate"
 from="0,266,278" to="360,266,278" dur="4s" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
```

```css
.container {
width:75vw;
height:auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" id="svg5" width="50%"  height="50%" viewBox="0 0 542 542" >
 <defs>
   <linearGradient id="Lg" x1="0" x2="0" y1="1" y2="0">
      <stop offset="0" stop-color="#DC143C" />
        <stop offset="0.8" stop-color="white" stop-opacity="0.05" />
   </linearGradient>
 </defs>   
<g id="g820" transform="translate(-658 -238)" fill="none" stroke="#707070" stroke-width="1">    
   
    <path id="Path_1" fill="black" stroke="black" d="m818 413 1 1c116 110 0 204 0 205l-1 1c-3 6 3 3 4 3a446 446 0 0 0 210-213c0-2-3-2-3-1-4 5-81 88-207 0h-4v4" data-name="Path 1" />
    <path id="Path_2" fill="#DC143C" d="M928 569s69 6 99 52c0 0 4 7 5 0a6 6 0 0 0 0-2c-3-8-31-77-55-99 0 0-35 38-49 49" data-name="Path 2" />
</g> 
   <circle id="Ellipse_3" data-name="Ellipse 3" stroke="url(#Lg)" cx="266" cy="278" r="220" fill="none" stroke="#DC143C" stroke-width="45" stroke-dasharray="251,1004" stroke-linecap="round" >
       <animateTransform attributeName="transform" attributeType="XML" type="rotate" from="0,266,278" to="360,266,278" dur="4s" repeatCount="indefinite"/>  
   </circle>   
   
</svg>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The **experimental** `<sprite-meister>` Web Component can generate the CSS for you

- After cleaning up your SVG: no translates, no self-closing tags
- You are left with the first frame of your animation

  - this is not SVG, but a String Template Literal you can program
- Sprite-Meister generates the other `steps=48` frames for you

  - the `circlepath` function calculates an `x,y` position for every frame
  - each `<circle cx="${v1.x}" cy="${v1.y}"` doesn't *rotate* the circle;
    it draws the circle at different positions in each frame
- and animates the generated SVG ***sprite-sheet*** with CSS

```html
<script src="//sprite-meister.github.io/element.js"></script>
<script>console.log=()=>{/*don't bloat SO snippet console*/}</script>

<sprite-meister duration="5s" w="542" h="542" width="180px" steps="48">
    ${ setv1( circlepath({ radius:200 }) , "yellow circle position" )}
    <text y="10%" font-size="50px">frame: ${framenr} </text>
    <path fill="green" d="m163 158 1 1c116 110 0 204 0 205l-1 1c-3 6 3 3 4 3a446 446 0 0 0 210-213c0-2-3-2-3-1-4 5-81 88-207 0h-4v4m105 150s69 6 99 52c0 0 4 7 5 0a6 6 0 0 0 0-2c-3-8-31-77-55-99 0 0-35 38-49 49"></path>
    <circle cx="${v1.x}" cy="${v1.y}" r="34" fill="yellow" stroke="blue"></circle>
</sprite-meister>
```

##### Sources:

- https://dev.to/dannyengelman/create-svg-spritesheet-animations-with-1-template-literal-string-3hee
- https://sprite-meister.github.io/
- https://sprite-meister.github.io/documentation.html

**`<sprite-meister>` is NOT version 1.0**

You need a decent amount of SVG knowlegde, and learn (at least the basics) of SVG SMIL animations first, so you understand the difference with *sprite-sheet animations*